# Smiles in output C++

Tags: c++

I'm writing Tic Tac Toe console game at the moment and I have one very funny problem. The program is working great, but the problem is in matrix of Tic Tac Toe. The last element (last row, last column) is a smile and it's sometimes changing. It is sometimes laughing smile, or it is a heart. What's wrong?

The whole code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
char matrix[3][3];
int orow, ocolumn, xrow, xcolumn;
int drawcounter = 0;
void paint() {
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = '_';
    }
}
void board() {
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
            if (i != 1 && j == 1)
                cout << endl;
            cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }

    cout << endl;
    //cout << matrix[3][3] << endl;

}

void action() {
    while (0 == 0) {
        puts("Time for player X. Enter index");
        cin >> xcolumn >> xrow;
        matrix[xcolumn][xrow] = 'X';
        drawcounter += 1;
        if (drawcounter == 9) {
            puts("It's a draw.");
            break;
        }
        board();
        cout << endl;
        if ((matrix[1][1] == 'X' && matrix[2][2] == 'X' && matrix[3][3] == 'X') || (matrix[1][3] == 'X' && matrix[2][2] == 'X' && matrix[3][1] == 'X')) {
            puts("X Wins! Congrats X!");
            break;
        }
        if ((matrix[1][1] == 'X' && matrix[1][2] == 'X' && matrix[1][3] == 'X') || (matrix[2][1] == 'X' && matrix[2][2] == 'X' && matrix[2][3] == 'X') || (matrix[3][1] == 'X' && matrix[3][2] == 'X' && matrix[3][3] == 'X')) {
            puts("X Wins! Congrats X!");
            break;
        }
        if ((matrix[1][1] == 'X' && matrix[2][1] == 'X' && matrix[3][1] == 'X') || (matrix[1][2] == 'X' && matrix[2][2] == 'X' && matrix[3][2] == 'X') || (matrix[1][3] == 'X' && matrix[2][3] == 'X' && matrix[3][3] == 'X')) {
            puts("X Wins! Congrats X!");
            break;
        }
        puts("Time for player O. Enter index");
        cin >> ocolumn >> orow;
        matrix[ocolumn][orow] = 'O';
        drawcounter += 1;
        board();
        cout << endl;
        if ((matrix[1][1] == 'O' && matrix[2][2] == 'O' && matrix[3][3] == 'O') || (matrix[1][3] == 'O' && matrix[2][2] == 'O' && matrix[3][1] == 'O')) {
            puts("O Wins! Congrats O!");
            break;
        }
        if ((matrix[1][1] == 'O' && matrix[1][2] == 'O' && matrix[1][3] == 'O') || (matrix[2][1] == 'O' && matrix[2][2] == 'O' && matrix[2][3] == 'O') || (matrix[3][1] == 'O' && matrix[3][2] == 'O' && matrix[3][3] == 'O')) {
            puts("O Wins! Congrats O!");
            break;
        }
        if ((matrix[1][1] == 'O' && matrix[2][1] == 'O' && matrix[3][1] == 'O') || (matrix[1][2] == 'O' && matrix[2][2] == 'O' && matrix[3][2] == 'O') || (matrix[1][3] == 'O' && matrix[2][3] == 'O' && matrix[3][3] == 'O')) {
            puts("O Wins! Congrats O!");
            break;
        }
    }
}
int main() {
    paint();
    board();
    action();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Output pictures:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The console window effect is because you're outputting bytes with values <32 (ASCII space). A Windows console window by default interprets many of these as graphical characters. This output is caused by a general bug: 1-based indexing, instead of C++ 0-based indexing.

Comment: "Is that UB in your output, or are you just happy to see me ?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array indexing in C/C++ start from `0`, not from `1` - so  you have to rewrite your code:

```
void paint() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = '_';
    }
}

void board() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (i != 0 && j == 0)
                cout << endl;
            cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }

    cout << endl;
    //cout << matrix[3][3] << endl;    
}
```

What's actually is going on here, in detail: when you define your array, you should remember that indexing starts from 0, so for example when you declare an array of 3 elements, `matrix[3]`, it's not going like `matrix[1]`, `matrix[2]`, and `matrix[3]`, but rather `matrix[0]`, `matrix[1]`, and `matrix[2]`.

So in this case you're getting out of an array bounds - and it's "here be dragons" territory outside of a memory region assigned to an array. So basically you're working with raw memory here, which in your situation contains a character code for a smiley face (and that's why it's different every time - because memory content isn't determined in this region - e.g., you can even try to get a value of `matrix[123]`, though its size is only 3 elements - and you get an undefined random value as a result).

And you should remember that C/C++ arrays behavior is very similar to pointers in this regard - you might even say that it's the same thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot,but when i'm started to code the Tic Tac Toe,I wanted that when I will input : 1 2, It will work perfectly(1 Column,2 Row). I was thinking that inputting 0 1, 0 2 was "ugly". So,OK,I will edit my code. Thanks.

Comment: You can stick with indices starting at `1`, you'd just have to declare a bigger array - i.e. `char matrix[4][4]` for a 3x3 game board.

Comment: @GùrìCôppérfîéld: Just subtract 1 from the number which was entered!

Answer (score 1):

In C++, arrays are indexed from 0. So in your loop  in `paint()`

```
for(int i = 1; i < 4; ++i) // out of bounds when `i = 3`
```

you have an out of bound access, as `matrix` is declared as

```
char matrix[3][3];
```

You have to replace all such loops with loops from 0 to 3. Also, your `if` conditions are probably wrong

```
if ((matrix[1][6] == 'X' && matrix[2][7] .... // 6 and 7 ?!?!
```

as the row/column indexes cannot be greater than 2

Comment: @GùrìCôppérfîéld The Q&A format StackOverflow follows requires that the question actually be a question (which includes not having the answer), and that the answer be voted to the top/accepted so that people from the future immediately see the "right" answer when they're done reading the question and deciding it fits their situation. Putting the solution in the question is a good idea in forums where the best answer can be buried 10 pages deep, but SO does not suffer from that.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> char matrix[3][3];
> ```

[...]

> ```
> matrix[3][3] == 'O'
> ```

This won't work. Array indices start at 0. So you've declared an array of size 3 and then access its 4th element. This is undefined behaviour. Which means *anything* can happen, including crashes or printing seemingly random characters.

Note that using raw arrays like this may raise an eyebrow or two. If you ever want the ability to determine matrix size dynamically (e.g. via user input), you will want to use `std::vector` anyway. And if the size is really conceptually meant to be known at compile time (which admittedly may be the case for a game like this), consider using `std::array`, or at least get informed on its syntax and benefits.

Comment: Oh, for a fixed size array like this a raw array is OK. I'm not so fond of `std::array` (which would be the standard library choice for a fixed size array). E.g. it's counter-intuitive to me to use some tuple function to obtain a compile time size, there is the create-it-with-size-from-initializer problem, etc. I think raw array for this is just fine.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Personally, I consider multi-dimensional raw arrays to be very unpleasent to read in code. With `std::array`, my head just seems to digest the syntax more easily. I'll edit the answer to reflect the fact that this is a somewhat subjective aspect.

Comment: Just define `template< int n, Type T > using Array = T[n];`. Then write e.g. `Array< 3, Array< 3, int > > matrix;`;-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are trying to store 1 in a char array as

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char n=1;
    cout << n;
    return 0;
 }
```

The output will be a smiley

Comment: Did you have a look at the other answers? Are you sure this brings something new to the table? Not saying it isn't correct, though.

Comment: I just answered the question , didn't saw any answer :)

Comment: It's because a few days back i was working on Pac Man that's why i just rapidly answered the question without reading what others think :) Sorry if you don't like my answer :)