# C Replace one character in an char array by another

Tags: c, arrays, string, replace, char

I have the following C Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    char c[] = "ABC"
    printf("%s ", c);
    c[1] = 'B';
    printf("%s", c);
    return 0;
}
```

The output I want is `ABC BBC` but the output I get is `ABC ABC`. How can I replace the first character in an String / char array?

Comment: Oh my good i feel so stupid. Of course the first element in an array is at index 0. First i tried to change c[3] to 'B' and got complete nonsense, and c[1] is already 'B', thanks for enlighting me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indexing in C arrays start from `0`. So you have to replace `c[1] = 'B'` with `c[0] = 'B'`.

Also, see similar question from today: [Smiles in output C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28631812/smiles-in-output-c/28631907#28631907) - I've put a more detailed description there :)

Answer (score 4):

Below is a code that ACTUALLY WORKS!

```
char * replace_char(char * input, char find, char replace) 
{

    char * output = (char*)malloc(strlen(input));

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++)
    {
        if (input[i] == find) output[i] = replace;
        else output[i] = input[i];
    }

    output[strlen(input)] = '\0';

    return output;

}
```

Comment: Yes, but it finds the character and copies the string, neither of which the question asked for...

Answer (score 2):

C arrays are zero base. The first element of the array is in the zero'th position.

```
c[0] = 'B';
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
c[0] = 'B';
```

arrays start at 0